# How can I get the average number of rows with repeated id?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table (user_notes) with these records:

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc3OA.jpg)

And I would like to get the average weight loss, the problem is that some users have repeated values. Example:

```
User 1: weight 20kg
User 1: weight 10kg --> Lost: 10kg
User 2: weight 100kg
User 2: weight 70kg --> Lost: 30kg

Avg weight loss: 20kg <-- Expected result
```

User 1 lost 10kg, User 2 lost 20kg but I need to do this for every userid and get an average weight loss.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Edit your question and provide a table (in the question) with more apt sample data and desired results.

Comment: How do you know which weight measurement is the `new` weight and which is the `old`?

Comment: What if there are more than 2 rows for a user, e.g. 90,80,75? Do you want to count this user 2 times (10 and 5 weight loss -> average of 7.5) or use a weight loss of 15?  What if it's 80,85,75?

Answer (score 1):

The challenge here is getting the first and last weight for each user.  Here is one way by aggregating at the user level to get the first and last weeks:

```
select tt.iduser, tmax.weight as last_weight, tmin.weight as first_weight,
       (tmax.weight - tmin.weight) as diff
from (select iduser, min(week) as minw, max(week) as maxw
      from t
      group by iduser
     ) tt join
     t tmin
     on tmin.iduser = tt.iduser and tmin.week = tt.minw join
     t tmax
     on tmax.iduser = tt.iduser and tmax.week = tt.maxw;
```

Then if you want the average weight loss:

```
select avg(tmax.weight - tmin.weight)
from (select iduser, min(week) as minw, max(week) as maxw
      from t
      group by iduser
     ) tt join
     t tmin
     on tmin.iduser = tt.iduser and tmin.week = tt.minw join
     t tmax
     on tmax.iduser = tt.iduser and tmax.week = tt.maxw
where maxw <> minw;
```

Comment: Maybe add a note that users with just one week would still be included in the results (with `diff` == 0)?

Comment: @Nicarus . . . That is a good idea.